# What is the difference between the Java operators >> and >>>?

Tags: java

What is the difference between the operator >> and >>>?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_C.2C_C.2B.2B_and_Java

Comment: That's eight... Hey come on. SO is a great place to learn but you are going to learn more, faster and better if you start here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`>>>` right shifts and fills with 0 at the left end, while `>>` fills with the sign bit.

This makes a difference for the signed integral types (i.e. all but `byte`), where a negative value has a set sign bit.

Answer (score 4):

`>>` Signed right shift operator and `>>>` unsigned right shift operator

**[Signed Right Shift Operator](http://www.roseindia.net/java/master-java/java-right-shift.shtml)**

> The  right shift `>>` operator shifts
>   the left operand to the right side
>   with sign extension by the number of
>   bits specified by its right operand.
>   This means that a value at n place
>   gets shifted to the right causing the
>   n high order bits that contains the
>   same value as that of unshifted value.
>   This operator never throws an
>   exception.

**[Unsigned Right Shift Operator](http://www.roseindia.net/java/master-java/java-unsigned-right-shift.shtml)**

> The unsigned right shift `>>>` operator
>   shifts a zero into the leftmost
>   position however the leftmost position
>   after ">>" depends on sign extension.

Answer (score 2):

> the signed right shift operator ">>"
>   shifts a bit pattern to the right. The
>   bit pattern is given by the left-hand
>   operand, and the number of positions
>   to shift by the right-hand operand.
>   The unsigned right shift operator
>   ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost
>   position, while the leftmost position
>   after ">>" depends on sign extension.

From http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation with examples:

http://www.roseindia.net/java/master-java/bitwise-bitshift-operators.shtml

`>>` fills in the sign the sign bit on the left (i.e. fills in 1 for negative values, 0 for positive), whereas `>>>` doesn't (always 0). This is convenient when shifting negative values. There is no `<<<`, since the sign bit is on the left and `<<` thus already behaves like `<<<` would (filling in zeros, nothing else).