# What does ">>>" in java mean?

Tags: java, python

im trying to translate this code to python, but im having a hard time doing so, don't worry about the index values and variable names, I just want to know what the ">>>" part does exactly, perhaps a python equivalent, but an explanation would be great:

```
target[0] = (char)(source[sourceIndex] >>> 2);
target[1] = (char)((source[sourceIndex] & 3) << 4 | source[sourceIndex + 1] >>> 4);
target[2] = (char)((source[sourceIndex + 1] & 0xf) << 2 | source[sourceIndex + 2] >>> 6);
target[3] = (char)(source[sourceIndex + 2] & 0x3f);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Its difficult to search for '>>>' on Google.

Comment: @Eels: That's a bit unfair, since it might not be obvious that the right search is "Java operators" rather than something like "java >>>".

Comment: I had no idea what this was called so googling for "java >>>" didnt return anything useful at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between >>> and >>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811319/difference-between-and)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "<<<" and ">>" are bit shift operators.  Specifically,

> The signed left shift operator "<<" shifts a bit pattern to the left, and the signed right shift operator ">>" shifts a bit pattern to the right. The bit pattern is given by the left-hand operand, and the number of positions to shift by the right-hand operand. The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position, while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on sign extension.

—— from [The Java™ Tutorials - Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Comment: Didn't you mean "<<" and ">>>" are bit shift operators?

Answer (score 10):

It's an "unsigned right shift".

So, if your number (`x`) is `11110000` (in binary).

`x >>> 1` will be `01111000` (in binary).

This is opposed to `x >> 1` which will result in `11111000` (in binary).

The `>>` tries to preserve the "sign bit" but the `>>>` does not.

Note: I've assumed a 8-bit integer (or a `byte` in Java). The same thing holds for 2-byte and 4-byte integers.

Answer (score 2):

Thats the unsigned right shift operator. It's a bitwise operator that shifts a zero into the leftmost bit of your operand. Here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html.