# What does >> and >>> mean in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between >>> and >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811319/difference-between-and)
>   [What does “>>>” in java mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444242/what-does-in-java-mean)

What does `>>` and `>>>` mean in Java?

Why does `-1 >> 2` and `-1 >>> 2` have different results?

Comment: Signed and unsigned shift right.

Comment: I should note, this was a nice and concise question that was reasonably well formatted. All-around good first question. Unfortunately, this question has been asked before, so I'm voting to close the question as a duplicate. I think it's worthwhile for you to read the [faq] if you haven't already (or at least [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) for some markdown tips).

Comment: Thanks, I'd check it and read the faq.

Answer (score 10):

`>>` is a signed right shift operator which shifts a bit pattern to the right.
`>>>` is an unsigned right shift operator which shifts a zero into the leftmost position. Please refer to [the Oracle Docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Comment: Good answer, but consider answering with an example instead of just pointing to one. I personally prefer seeing an example over clicking a link to see one.

Answer (score 7):

In java, there are 2 types of right shifts. >>> will attach 0's to fill the empty spaces for both positive and negative numbers (logical shift right) while >> will attach 1's if negative and 0's if positive (sign extension).