# What do << or >>> in java mean?

Tags: java, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does >> and >>> mean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255420/what-does-and-mean-in-java)

I ran across some unfamiliar symbols in some java code, and while the code compiles and functions correctly, I am confused as to what exactly the angle brackets are doing in this code.  I found the code in [com.sun.java.help.search.BitBuffer](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/com/sun/java/help/search/BitBuffer.java.html), a fragment of which is below:

```
public void append(int source, int kBits)
    {
        if (kBits < _avail)
        {
            _word = (_word << kBits) | source;
            _avail -= kBits;
        }
        else if (kBits > _avail)
        {
            int leftover = kBits - _avail;
            store((_word << _avail) | (source >>> leftover));
            _word = source;
            _avail = NBits - leftover;
        }
        else
        {
            store((_word << kBits) | source);
            _word = 0;
            _avail = NBits;
        }
    }
```

What do those mysterious looking brackets do?  It *almost* looks like c++ insertion/extraction, but I know that Java doesn't have anything like that.

Also, I tried googling it, but for some reason Google seems to not see the angle brackets, even if I put them in quotes.

Comment: They are Bit-Shift operators, read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) and more detailed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Comment: Just to add, >>> right shifting of bits means dividing the number by no of bit shifts raised to the power of 2 and << left shifting of bits means multiplying the number by no of bit shifts raised to the power of 2

Answer (score 48, accepted):

They are Bitwise Bit shift operators, they operate by shifting the number of bits being specified .  Here is [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) on how to use them.

> The signed left shift operator "<<" shifts a bit pattern to the left
>
> The signed right shift operator ">>" shifts a bit pattern to the
> right.
>
> The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the
> leftmost position

Comment: The code is also using `>>>` which is an unsigned right shift.

Comment: @TheZ: Thanks! Updated answer with related text.

Answer (score 8):

straight from [ORACLE DOC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

> The signed left shift operator "<<" shifts a bit pattern to the left,
>   and the signed right shift operator ">>" shifts a bit pattern to the
>   right. The bit pattern is given by the left-hand operand, and the
>   number of positions to shift by the right-hand operand. The unsigned
>   right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position,
>   while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on sign extension.

Answer (score 4):

Bitwise shifting. Please see the official docs here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html