# what is has_zero and find_zero in word_at_a_time.h used for

Tags: c, hash, linux-kernel

In linux kernel, inlucde/linux/word_at_a_time.h, there are two functions:

```
static inline long find_zero(unsigned long mask)
{
        long byte = 0;
#ifdef CONFIG_64BIT
        if (mask >> 32)
                mask >>= 32;
        else
                byte = 4;
#endif
        if (mask >> 16)
                mask >>= 16;    
        else
                byte += 2;
        return (mask >> 8) ? byte : byte + 1;
}

static inline bool has_zero(unsigned long val, 
                            unsigned long *data, 
                            const struct word_at_a_time *c)
{
        unsigned long rhs = val | c->low_bits;
        *data = rhs;
        return (val + c->high_bits) & ~rhs;
}
```

It's used in a hash function, in git log it says:

> ```
>  - has_zero(): take a word, and determine if it has a zero byte in it.
>    It gets the word, the pointer to the constant pool, and a pointer to
>    an intermediate "data" field it can set.
> ```

But I still don't get

(1) What this function do?, and
(2) How they do it?

Comment: The function looks like it performs a binary search of the bytes within the word `mask` and returns the index of the highest byte that is zero.

Comment: Those functions are definitely unclear and ill-named. And no comments either ? That strange, I would have expected more from the linux kernel devs... Any kernel dev here ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan indeed I never said that the function was not good. Just that if a contributor needs to ask on SO for its use, then I think knowledge is not transferred very efficiently in the team ;) Suggestions for efficient knowledge transfer 1) adequate naming of functions and variables 2) comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose bits are numbered from Least Significant Bit (LSB) (numbered 0) to Most  Significant Bit (MSB).

### What it does?

Function `find_zero()` search **first** `N` (<=7) bytes with value zero from left hand side using a technique similar to divide and conquer.

### How it does?

Suppose a 64 bit-system  where `CONFIG_64BIT` is defined, then following piece of code executes:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_64BIT
        if (mask >> 32)  //Any bit=1 in left 32 bits 
                mask >>= 32;
        else
                byte = 4;  //<--No, fist 4 bytes are zero
```

First note `mask` is `unsigned`, so `>>` is unsigned right sift. ([like Java's >>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457893/java-right-shift-on-negative-number/15457908#15457908))

It first checks in if for `mask` value is more then  2<sup>32</sup> (or we can say if in `unsigned long mask` any bit between bit numbered `32` to `63` is one).

`mask >> 32` will produces a pure value that is its `mask` right-shifted with zero `0` extension by `32` bits and causes the `32` high order bits to contain zero.

for example, if `maks` bits are as follows:

```
63     56 55     48 47     40 39     32 31     24 23     16 15        7       0
▼       ▼ ▼       ▼ ▼       ▼ ▼       ▼ ▼       ▼ ▼       ▼ ▼         ▼       ▼
0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0101
▲                                                                             ▲
MSB                                                                         LSM
```

In this example, bit number `34` and `59` is one, so `(mask >> 32)` == `true` (or say non-zero `!0`). Hence for this example `if (mask >> 32)` == `if(!0)`.
In genral, if any bit from bit number `32` to `63` is one then `mask` will be updated to `mask >>= 32;` == `mask =  mask >> 32;` (as if true and if statement executes). This causes high order `32` bits becomes low order `32` bits due to right shift (and bits 32 to 63 becomes `0`).

In above example `mask` becomes:

```
           shifted OLD bit number ----> 63                 45                32
63                  47               32 31                 15                 0
▼                   ▼                 ▼ ▼                   ▼                 ▼
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100
▲                                                                             ▲
MSB                                                                         LSM
|-------------------------------------|
| All are zero                        |
```

Note: bits from 32 to 63 are `0` and bits from `0` to `31` copied from bits `32` to `63` from above.

Upto here:

**Case-1:**
If any bit from `32` to `63` is *one* in original `mask` then `if` executes true and mask updates. (as I explained above). And variable `long byte`  remains `0`. Then in next `if(mask >> 16)`, function `find_zero()` will continue to search for a byte with value zero within bit range `48` to `63`(In `if(mask >> 16)`, bit numbered `48` to `63` will be checked for if any bit is 1).

**Case-2:**
If all bits from `32` to `63` are zero in original `mask`, then `if` condition becomes false (that is `if(mask >> 32)` == `if(0)`) and `mask` doesn't updates, and variable `long byte` becomes `4`, and This indicates that high four bytes are `0` in `mask`. After this in `if(mask >> 16)`, function `find_zero()`  will search for a byte with zero in bit range `16` to `31`.

Similarly, in Second `if()`:

```
if (mask >> 16)
  mask >>= 16;    
else
  byte += 2;
```

It will checks if any bit between bit numbered `16 to 31` is one or not. If all bits are zero then `byte` will incremented by `2` in else part, in if-part mask will be updated by unsigned shift right 16-bits.
(**Note**: if `mask` is updated `mask` then actually this `if(mask >> 16)` checking whether any bit between `48 to 63` is one, otherwise bits `16` to `31` in original mask)

Subsequently, last conditional operator works in similar fashion to check any bit between bit numbed `8` to `15` is one or not.

```
                  long byte = 0;
                  64 bit `mask`
                       |
                       |
                       ▼
            if(any bit from 32 to 62 is one)---+
            |                                  |
            |False: if(0)                      |True: if(!0)
      all bits between 32 to 64              |A byte=Zero NOT found
      are zero                         Some bits are one from bit 32-63
            |                                  |
            |                                  |
        byte = 4                          byte= 0, and
        64 bit `mask`  <--Orignal       `mask` updated as `mask >>= 32;`
           |                                        |
           |                                        |
           ▼                                        ▼
if(Any bit from 16 to 31 is one)       if(Any bit from 48 to 63 is one)
   |Because high order bits are Zero    |Note due to >> all high order
   |It check for bits numbered 16-31    |bits becomes zero.
   |                                    |2nd if checks for bit from 16-31
   |                                    |that were originally bit
   |                                    | numbered 48 to 63
   |                                    |
   ▼                                    ▼
Case False: if(0)                        Case False: if(0)
     All bits Zero from 16-31               All bits Zero from 49-63
     mask will NOT updated and              mask will NOT updated and
     byte = 6                                  byte = 2

Case True: if(!0)                         Case False: if(!0)
    Some bits are one from 16-31         Some bits are one from 49-63
    mask updated                            mask Updated
     byte = 4                                  byte = 0
   |                                        |
   |                                        |
   ▼                                        ▼
more four cases                          more four cases

Total 8 different answer outputs from `0` to `7`
```

So function `find_zero()` search **first** `N` bytes with value zero from left hand side. Output byte value can be from `0` to `7` and doesn't considers right most byte (`"8"`).
(*note: long is 64 bits long = 8 * 8-bits = 8 bytes.*)

```
byte NUMBER ("):      
   "1"       "2"        "3"       "4"       "5"       "6"       "7"       "8"
63     56 55     48 47     40 39     32 31     24 23     16 15        7       0
▼       ▼ ▼       ▼ ▼       ▼ ▼       ▼ ▼       ▼ ▼       ▼ ▼         ▼       ▼
0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0101
▲                                                                             ▲
MSB                                                                         LSM
```

byte = `0` --> means first byte is not zero
byte = `1` --> high order byte is zero that is bit numbered `56` to `63`
byte = `2` --> two high order bytes are zero that is bit numbered `48` to `63`
byte = `3` --> three high order byte is zero that is bit numbered `40` to `63`
   :
   :
Similarly, byte = `7` --> Seven bytes from left are 0, (or all 0).

### Flow-diagram

> [image: flow-diagram]

### Code

Below I have written a small code that calls `find_zero()` function with different values, will help you to understand the function:

```
int main(){ 
 printf("\nmask=0x0, all bytes are zero, result =%ld", find_zero(0x0L)); // not prints 8
 printf("\nmask=0xff, left seven bytes are zero, result =%ld", find_zero(0xffL));
 printf("\nmask=0xffff, left six bytes are zero, result =%ld", find_zero(0xffffL));
 printf("\nmask=0xffffff, left five bytes are zero, result =%ld", find_zero(0xffffffL));
 printf("\nmask=0xffffffff, left four bytes are zero, result =%ld", find_zero(0xffffffffL));
 printf("\nmask=0xffffffffff, left three bytes are zero, result =%ld", find_zero(0xffffffffffL));
 printf("\nmask=0xffffffffffff, left two bytes are zero, result =%ld", find_zero(0xffffffffffffL));
 printf("\nmask=0xffffffffffffff, left most one byte is zero, result =%ld", find_zero(0xffffffffffffffL));
 printf("\nmask=0xffffffffffffffff, No byte is zero, result =%ld", find_zero(0xffffffffffffffffL));
 printf("\nmask=0x8000000000000000L, first byte is NOT zero (so no search), result =%ld", find_zero(0x8000000000000000LL));  
    printf("\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Please observe the output to understand function:

```
mask=0x0, all bytes are zero, result =7
mask=0xff, left seven bytes are zero, result =7
mask=0xffff, left six bytes are zero, result =6
mask=0xffffff, left five bytes are zero, result =5
mask=0xffffffff, left four bytes are zero, result =4
mask=0xffffffffff, left three bytes are zero, result =3
mask=0xffffffffffff, left two bytes are zero, result =2
mask=0xffffffffffffff, left most one byte is zero, result =1
mask=0xffffffffffffffff, No byte is zero, result =0
mask=0x8000000000000000L, first byte is NOT zero (so no search), result =0
```

Note: if all bytes are zero it prints `7` not 8.

Comment: I think you jumped into **how** the function does it, without the **what**.

Comment: @ugoren Notice last few lines: **What** = `function find_zero() search first byte with value zero from left hand side`, Also read what is meaning of `byte = 0-7`

Comment: The problem is that **what** shouldn be in the first few lines, not the last.

Comment: @ugoren I agree Ugoren, actually question is tough to me as well :) ..I came to result at last. Thanks for your feed back I will update answer as I find time.

Comment: OP @dspjm  read `has_zero()` from [The word-at-a-time interface](http://lwn.net/Articles/501492/).`has_zero()` *`is a simple boolean function that returns true if value contains a zero byte.`* I am myself tryig  to explore it

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan So elaborate and it's a guilt not to choose to you as the best answer. How did you make those graphs in text? All by hand, if you have a tool to do this, please let me know, I am looking for it.

Comment: @ugoren Check now! **how** & **what**  :)

Answer (score 0):

The first function looks for the first byte in the mask that is not null, and returns its index starting from the left.

Example for 64bit, `xx` meaning "any byte" and "nn" meaning "non-zero byte" :

```
.nn.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx -> find_zero() -> 0
.00.nn.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx -> find_zero() -> 1
.00.00.nn.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx -> find_zero() -> 2
...
.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.nn -> find_zero() -> 7
.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00 -> find_zero() -> 7 (this one is strange)
```

I would have named this function `find_first_significant_byte_index()` if not for the last case which is ambiguous...

The second function splits `val` according to a bitmask, stores its "low_bits" in *data for further reference and returns some strange op result on val. (Can't identify for sure this last one).

Answer (score 0):

See "The word-at-a-time interface": https://lwn.net/Articles/501492/

has_zero() returns a non-zero mask if the input has a zero-byte within it.

find_zero() finds where *that* first zero was using the mask as the input (technically, it's not *that* mask, but that mask further massaged by two more functions). find_zero() is NOT finding a zero in the input mask.

See example usage in linked article:

```
if (has_zero(value, &bits, &constants)) {
    bits = prep_zero_mask(value, bits, &constants);
    bits = create_zero_mask(bits);
    zero_byte = find_zero(bits);
    /* ... */
```