# How Linux kernel function (bitmap_set ..) works

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am trying to see code about kgpu and can't understand some function.
could anyone help me to explain the following Linux kernel function :

`bitmap_set` , `bitmap_find_next_zero_ares`

thanks to explain and hope to give me an example .

Comment: bitmap_find_next_zero_area - find a contiguous aligned zero area using [`find_zero()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997515/what-is-has-zero-and-find-zero-in-word-at-a-time-h-used-for)  function.

Comment: The code is architecture specific in implementation.  Please add your CPU type for a specific description.  In some cases, interrupt are masked to ensure the operation is atomic.  In other cases, assembler primitives can be used with out locking interrupts.  The **LWN** link by [Hasturkun](http://stackoverflow.com/users/20270/hasturkun) is great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having more context makes answering difficult, but as these are defined as functions in the Linux kernel I suspect this is a fragment of an initializer somewhere defining an array of function addresses.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/bitmap.c#L276

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/bitmap.c#L330