# Change Spinner options based on another Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I am trying to implement a user search through my database with the use of spinners.

I have fleets and vehicles(fleets contain vehicles). I have a list of fleets as one spinner and a list of vehicles as the other.

By default I want the fleets to be set to "All" and the vehicle one to show all the vehicles(This is currently the case), however when the fleet input is changed to a particular one, say fleet1, the vehicle spinner should update accordingly[this  will be implemented via SQLite database search but I don't think the issue is here].

How do I make a listener for when fleet spinner data is changed?

```
vehicleSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.vehicleSpinner); 
      String selected = (String)fleetSpinner.getSelectedItem();
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter5 = null;
      if(selected == "All"){
          //show all vehicles
          adapter5 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, vehicleArrayListString);

  }else{
      String vehiclesInFleetQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Database.TABLE_VEHICLE + " WHERE " + Database.COLUMN_FLEET + "='" + selected +"'";
      Log.i(TAG,"QUERY: "+ vehiclesInFleetQuery);
      Cursor cursor = Database.listOfVehiclesDesired(query);


        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
             String addToList = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.COLUMN_VEHICLE_ID));
             vehicleArrayFleet.add(addToList);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }else{//error on fleet search, no vehicles in fleet
            vehicleArrayFleet = vehicleArrayListString;
            builderContinue.setMessage("Selected Fleet(" + selected + ") had zero associated vehicles").setTitle("Error").show();
        }


        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            System.out.println("Closed");
            cursor.close();
        }

       adapter5 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, vehicleArrayFleet);
  }


 adapter5.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
  vehicleSpinner.setAdapter(adapter5);
```

Comment: you have delete that question good, but its not done ...wait I have better gift for you :) :) , if you need respond to me

Comment: Ok go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457893/java-right-shift-on-negative-number/15457908#15457908)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an OnItemSelectedListener for the fleet spinner.  You can find an example at http://start-jandroid.blogspot.com/2011/01/android-spinner-example.html.  From the listener in the fleet spinner, you can set the selected item of the vehicle spinner.