# how to multiply two negative values without using the multiplication (*) function in java

Tags: java, multiplication, negative-number

For example, I have this code to multiply 2 numbers without using the * symbol, but how can I achieve the same with negative numbers?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int result = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
    int num1 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
    int num2 = in.nextInt();
   if(num1==0 || num2==0) {
       System.out.println("the profuct of these numbers is: 0");
     }

    for(int i =0; i <num1; i++)

    {
        result += num2;            
    }
    System.out.println("the profuct od these numbers is: "+result);

}

}
```

Comment: Hint: if X is less than 0, then treat it as `X = -1 * abs(X);`.

Comment: Hint: Two negative numbers multiplied make a positive one.

Comment: Hint: your code works with adding additional minus signs in front of the num1 in for loop and result at the end.

Comment: why do you wana do that? keyboard broken? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only one number is negative, you can use the same approach, but you need to make sure that you use the positive one in the cycle (as `num1` in your code). If both numbers are negative, you can change both of them to positive using `abs(num)` and nothing changes.

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.Maths.abs(num1/2)` for iteration and

something like:

```
if(num1<0^num2<0){
    result = 0 - result;
}
```

between interation and output.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

```
BigInteger num1 = new BigInteger(-12);
BigInteger num2 = new BigInteger(-13);
BigInteger result  = num1.multiply(num2);
```

Also you may use bitwise [shifting and adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776211/how-can-i-multiply-and-divide-using-only-bit-shifting-and-adding) and try this [on negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457893/java-right-shift-on-negative-number?rq=1).

Of course you can mutiply values your way and just make it positive or negative - you know the rules.

Comment: Well, this clearly multiplies without using the `*` operator, but I don't think that's what OP is going for.

Comment: -1: The question seems obviously to be a homework/exercise to emulate multiplication using loops. While this *solves* the problem directly, won't help OP to learn about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Keep what you have but keep track of how many negatives you have and use the absolute value.

```
bool resultNeg = false;
if( num1 < 0 && num2 > 0 || num1 > 0 && num2 < 0 )
    resultNeg = true;

num1 = Math.abs( num1 ); num2 = Math.abs( num2 );

for( int i = 0; i < num1; ++i )
{
    // ...
}

if( resultNeg ) result = 0 - result;

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int result = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
    int num1 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
    int num2 = in.nextInt();
    if(num1==0 || num2==0) {
        System.out.println("the profuct of these numbers is: 0");
        return;
    }

    String sign = "";
    if (num1 < 0 && num2 > 0)
    {
        sign = "-";
    }
    if (num2 < 0 && num1 > 0)
    {
        sign = "-";
    }

    num1 = abs(num1);
    num2 = abs(num2);
    for(int i =0; i <num1; i++)
    {
        result += num2;            
    }
    System.out.println("the profuct of these numbers is: "+sign+result);
}
```