# Converting integer into four byte array

Tags: java, sockets, arrays

Currently I am working on socket programming where I have to send array of bytes to the firmware.The below code is for converting int into byte array.

```
    public static byte[] intToFourByteArray(int value) {
    return new byte[]{
        (byte) (value),
        (byte) (value >> 8),
        (byte) (value >> 16),
        (byte) (value >> 24)};

}
```

Can anyone make me understand how this right shift works,with small example.

and this is the oposite converting byte into int.

```
  public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b) {
    return b[0] & 0xFF
            | (b[1] & 0xFF) << 8
            | (b[2] & 0xFF) << 16
            | (b[3] & 0xFF) << 24;
}
```

How this left shift and right shift works.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15457917/1076640) explains how shifts work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can simply convert `int` value to 4 `byte` `array` using the below statement.

```
return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(intVal).array();
```

But before implementing this, first have a look at the documentation of [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), especially on the [`order`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order%28java.nio.ByteOrder%29) method.

In order to understand the left shift & right shift, go to this StackOverflow answer: [Java: right shift on negative number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457893/java-right-shift-on-negative-number/15457917#15457917)

Shishir

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ByteBuffer`:

```
public static byte[] intToBytes(final int i)
{
    return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(i).array();
}

public static int bytesToInt(final byte[] b)
{
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(b).getInt();
}
```

Note that the default ordering is big endian. This is the JVM's, and also network, byte order.

Answer (score 0):

Things to know to understand that code:

- `int` to `byte` conversion cuts off the 3 most significant bytes of the `int`.
- Shifts
- Bitmasks
- When you hard-code the value `0xFF` it's actually an `int` (`0x000000FF`). You `&` the bytes with it to get rid of the leading 1's you get in signed `byte`-to-`int` conversion when the `byte` is negative (has a 1 in the most significant bit).

So suppose your `int` was `0x1A2B3C4D`:

```
public static byte[] intToFourByteArray(int value) {
    return new byte[]{
        (byte) (value),        // Cuts off top, leaves 0x4D
        (byte) (value >> 8),   // Shift gives 0x001A2B3C, cut-off leaves 0x3C
        (byte) (value >> 16),  // Shift gives 0x00001A2B, cut-off leaves 0x2B
        (byte) (value >> 24)}; // Shift gives 0x0000001A, cut-off leaves 0x1A

}
```

And suppose we fed the byte array `0x4D, 0x3C, 0x2B, 0x1A` back:

```
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b) {
    return b[0] & 0xFF             // That gives 0x0000004D
            | (b[1] & 0xFF) << 8   // Gives 0x0000003C then shifts to 0x00003C00
            | (b[2] & 0xFF) << 16  // Same idea, giving 0x002B0000
            | (b[3] & 0xFF) << 24; // ...and 0x1A000000
}                                  // Finally, the or-ing of them together gives 0x1A2B3C4D
```