# Right Shifting with negative Shift Value on Negative Integer

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Hey i was trying to run the following block of code which actually Right shifts a Negative Integer number using negative shift value. Something like `(negative integer)>>(negative shift value)`.

But interestingly what is found is that what is that whatever the value of shift & The value of integer every time it produces a result of `-1`. Plz Explain why the answer is always `-1`.

Example:

```
      -8>>-9
      Result: -1
      -10>>-8
      Result: -1
      -8>>-2
      Result: -1
```

This question is actually about how negative shift values work on negative integer integer values for right shifting using >> and not about simple Binary right shifts.

Comment: Read this
http://geekexplains.blogspot.co.il/2009/05/binary-rep-of-negative-numbers-in-java.html

Comment: @GuyKhmel Thanks for the URL. But what i really want to know is what does right shifting with a negative shift value actually does?

Comment: @Prometheus Another article I found is this: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30868&seqNum=6
Check out the last example

Comment: @GuyKhmel Please be more Specific.

Comment: The result is not *always* -1, that just tends to happen when the negative numbers are both close to zero.

Comment: @Prometheus, in their example they show the following: `int j = -20;` 

`int result2 = j >> 2; // result = -5`
So the shift right when the case is negative numbers on both is the same as positive

Comment: @NikhilYekhe That post doesn't appear to cover shifting negative values.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [Java: right shift on negative number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15457893)

Answer (score -1):

My explanation would be this:

According to [This article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30868&seqNum=6)

Shift right is the same as dividing it by a power of two.
Same goes when you use negative numbers on both sides (`-8>>-9`) just with negative values. For example `-8>>-1  =>  -4`

And when you come down to -1 then you get `-1 / 2 => -1` like the behaviour in for Integers

Comment: Shifting with -9 actually shifts with `-9 & 0x1f` == 17 for int or `-9 & 0x3f` == 37 for long, the -1 is simply because in Java shifting left with `>>` uses sign-extension, and both 17 and 37 will shift out any zero bits in the case of -8.

Comment: Oops, that should have read "shifting right"...