# Why do we do unsigned right shift or signed right shift?

Tags: operators, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Why do we do unsigned right shift?. [What is the purpose of the unsigned right shift operator ">>>" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763917/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-unsigned-right-shift-operator-in-java)

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
     int a = 60;    /* 60 = 0011 1100 */  

     c = a << 2;     /* 240 = 1111 0000 */
     System.out.println("a << 2 = " + c );

     c = a >> 2;     /* 215 = 1111 */
     System.out.println("a >> 2  = " + c );

     c = a >>> 2;     /* 215 = 0000 1111 */
     System.out.println("a >>> 2 = " + c );
  }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16763943/2805694. I looked into the first answer and others too in the topic but not able to understand on **why do we do it**.

Comment: We do it when we want to perform a right shift.  I'm not sure how else to answer this...

Comment: shane u understand the diff right?

Comment: @Kal: i understand the difference of both....

Comment: Read [Java: right shift on negative number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457893/java-right-shift-on-negative-number/15457908#15457908)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Why do we need it?. There should be some scenario or situations which might need this...

Comment: @Shane I read somewhere unsigned shifts useful in graphics programming, I don't know how.. google it.

Comment: Isn't this like "why do we use multiplication"? You need it when you need it. Naming any specific scenario wouldn't do it justice.