# What is this JavaScript operator doing?

Tags: javascript

I've seen the following:

```
((2 * 45) + (2 * 124) + 100) >>> 3
```

Putting this in a console on its own reveals the value 54.

What is the purpose of >>> 3?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: [Some more info here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077902/bitwise-operation-zero-fill-right-shift-usages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [Zero-fill right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift) bitwise operator.

From the Mozilla Developer Network docs:

> This operator shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to the right. Excess bits shifted off to the right are discarded. Zero bits are shifted in from the left. The sign bit becomes 0, so the result is always non-negative.