# Switching the first 4 bits of a byte and the last half

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I need to switch the first half and the second half of a `byte: Make 0011 0101 to 0101 0011` for example

I thought it might work this way:
For example, i have `1001 1100`
i `bitshift` to the `left 4` times and get `1111 1001`(because if the first bit is a 1 the others become a one too)
i bitshift to the `right 4` times and `get 1100 0000`(the second half of the byte gets filled with 0s)
i don't want `1111 1001` but `0000 1001` so i do `0x00001111 & 1111 1001` (which filters the frist 4 bits) to make `1111 1001 to 0000 1001`
then i add everything up:

```
0000 1001 + 1100 0000 = 1100 1001
```

I got this:

> bytes[i] = (byte) (( 0x00001111 & (bytes[i] >> 4)) +  (bytes[i] << 4)
>   );
>
> here is one output:  11111111 to 00000001

I do not really understand why this is happening, I know the binary System and I think I know how bitshifting works but I can't explain this one. 
Sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the `>>>` operation, which shifts the sign bits without sign extending so zero bits will fill in on the left.  The problem is that it is an integer operation.  The `>>` works the same way except it sign extends thru the int.

```java
  int i = -1;
  i >>>= 30;
  System.out.println(i); // prints 3 as expected.

  byte b = -1;
  b >>>= 6;
  System.out.printnln(b); // prints -1 ???
```

The byte is still -1 because `byte b = -1` was shifted as though it was an int then reassigned to a byte.  So the byte remained negative.  To get 3, you would need to do something that seems strange, like the following.

```java
   byte b = -1;
   b >>>=30;
   System.out.println(b); // prints 3
```

So to do your swap you need to do the following;

```java
   byte b = 0b10100110;
   b = (byte)(((b>>>4)&0xF)|(b<<4));
```

The `0xF` mask, masks off those lingering high order bits left over from the conversion from integer back to byte.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the syntax for bit manipulation in Java, although here's how you can do it.

```
bitmask = 0x1111;
firstHalf = ((bytes[i] >> 4) & bitmask);
secondHalf = ((bytes[i] & bitmask) << 4)
result = firstHalf | secondHalf;
```

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Yes, basically for it to be 1111 (or 00001111).

Comment: OP also wrote it that way but in hexadecimal it should be `0x0F`

Comment: thank you and  thank @CarlosHeuberger :bytes[i] = (byte) (( 0b00001111 & (bytes[i] >> 4)) +  (bytes[i] << 4) ) works, i just  didnt knew whats the difference between 0x and 0b

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want `1111 1001` but `0000 1001`

If so, you need to use [shift right zero fill operator(>>>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077902/bitwise-operation-zero-fill-right-shift-usages) instead of preserving sign of the number.

I don't think the formula found works properly.

```
 public byte reverseBitsByte(byte x) {
  int intSize = 8;
  byte y=0;
  for(int position=intSize-1; position>0; position--){
    y+=((x&1)<<position);
    x >>= 1;
  }
  return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int swapBits(int a)  {
    // Написать решение сюда ↓
    int right = (a & 0b00001111);
    right= (right<<4);
    int left = (a & 0b11110000);
    left = (left>>4);
    return (right | left);
}
```