# Why -2>>>1 equals 2147483647 in Java

Tags: java, operator-keyword, twos-complement, ones-complement

`-2`'s one's complement is 100000...01

`-2`'s two's complement is 1000000...10

```
-2 >>> 1
```

According `>>>` definition left side shifts in 0

should be something like  `01000......1`, why becomes `0111111..11`?

Comment: `>>>` is the unsigned right shift operator and doesn't look at the sign bit like `>>` does .. [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763917/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-unsigned-right-shift-operator-in-java)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to produce two's complement representation of `2` (i.e. `-2`'s representation) you start with the representation of `2`, flip all its bits, and add `1` to the result:

```
00000000000000000000000000000010 -- This is 2
11111111111111111111111111111101 -- This the inverse of 2
11111111111111111111111111111110 -- This is the inverse of 2, plus 1
```

`-2`'s binary representation is `11111111111111111111111111111110` ([demo](http://ideone.com/TiOeI1)).

Shifting it over to the right by one without sign-extension produces

```
01111111111111111111111111111111
```

which is precisely the result that you get.