# Difference between >>= and >>>=

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out the difference between >>= and >>>=. I understand what they do, but i don't understand the difference.
The following has an output of 38 152 38 152. 
The bit-wise assignment >>>= seems to be doing exactly the same as >>=.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int c = 153;
    System.out.print((c >>= 2));
    System.out.print((c <<= 2));
    System.out.print((c >>>= 2));
    System.out.print((c <<= 2));
}
```

Comment: `I understand what they do` What do they do? 100% of your grade depends on your answer.

Comment: You can find the difference between `>>=` and `>>>=` (and between `>>` and `>>>`) when you attempt these operators on negative numbers.

Comment: Explanation, including the difference between `>>` and `>>>`, here: [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Comment: Tale a look at [Absolute Beginner's Guide to Bit Shifting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting). Also [Difference between >>> and >>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811319/difference-between-and)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read more about [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

```
>>      Signed right shift
>>>     Unsigned right shift
```

The bit pattern is given by the left-hand operand, and the number of positions to shift by the right-hand operand. The unsigned right shift operator `>>>` *shifts a **zero** into the leftmost position*,

while the leftmost position after `>>` depends on sign extension.

In simple words `>>>` always *shifts a **zero** into the leftmost position* whereas `>>` shifts based on sign of the number i.e. 1 for negative number and 0 for positive number.

---

For example try with negative numbers.

```
int c = -153;
System.out.printf("%32s%n",Integer.toBinaryString(c >>= 2));
System.out.printf("%32s%n",Integer.toBinaryString(c <<= 2));
System.out.printf("%32s%n",Integer.toBinaryString(c >>>= 2));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(c <<= 2));

c = 153;
System.out.printf("%32s%n",Integer.toBinaryString(c >>= 2));
System.out.printf("%32s%n",Integer.toBinaryString(c <<= 2));
System.out.printf("%32s%n",Integer.toBinaryString(c >>>= 2));
System.out.printf("%32s%n",Integer.toBinaryString(c <<= 2));
```

output:

```
11111111111111111111111111011001
11111111111111111111111101100100
  111111111111111111111111011001
11111111111111111111111101100100
                          100110
                        10011000
                          100110
                        10011000
```

Comment: It might be clearer if, rather than using `System.out.println(x)` (for some x), you used `System.out.printf("%32d%n", x)` to get them right-justified, although I'm not sure if it would.

Comment: @DavidConrad Thanks but I want to display it in binary format as well to make it more clear. I have updated it in my post.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I meant to write `%32s`. Brain fart.