# What does >>> mean in java

Tags: java

I am having a hard time understanding the `>>>` bitwise operator in java .

```
 int a = 60;
 int c = 0;
 c = a >>> 2;
 System.out.println("a >>> 2 = " + c );
```

Result is 15

But how does it become 15 ?

Comment: how do you google Logical right shift if you don't know its name?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html - quick explanation of bitwise and bitshift operators.

Comment: @1010: Guess what happens if you just Google using this question's title?

Comment: Related: [Difference between >>> and >>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811319/difference-between-and).

Comment: @Crowder I get reference to other operators. But worse, the SO suggestions when you write the title must have shown some duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

60 in binary is 111100. Right-shift two and you get 1111. That's 15

Comment: to the right, right?

Comment: So i start removing bits from the right

Comment: you're shifting the entire binary representation right. so yes, you're removing bits on the right.

Comment: @Ryan so for a binary such as `11001110` its becomes `110011` (removing 2 right most bits)