# Getting a grey level image back from a color image in android after bitwise extraction

Tags: java, android

The following code shows a part of my code. 
When I delete the part between '// start of color extraction & composing'
and '// end of color extraction & composing' I always get the same color image back
in tmpBmp. But if I insert the part, then I always get a grey-level image
displayed (whereas I'm expecting the same color image). 
Is there any reason that the code between '// start of color extraction & composing' and '// end of color extraction & composing' returns a grey-scaled image?

```
int width = captureBmp.getWidth();
int height = captureBmp.getHeight();
int red, green, blue, alpha;

Bitmap tmpBmp = captureBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
     int value = captureBmp.getPixel(x, y);

 //  start of color extraction & composing
   alpha = value & 0xFF000000 >> 24;         
       red = value & 0x00FF0000 >> 16;
   green = value & 0x0000FF00 >> 8;
   blue = value & 0x000000FF;

   value = ( (alpha << 24) & 0xFF000000) |
          ( (red << 16) & 0x00FF0000) |
          ((green << 8) & 0x0000FF00) |
      (blue & 0x000000FF);
   //  end of color extraction & composing


              tmpBmp.setPixel(x, y, value);
                }
            }
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
imgView.setImageBitmap(tmpBmp);
```

Comment: What are the actual `alpha`, `red`, `green`, and `blue` values?

Comment: They correspond to the alpha, red, green and blue components of the color pixel in ARGB format. After fixing the code as answered below I got the corresponding components.

Comment: I know, but I was asking what their actual values are.  It's okay, it looks like your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
red = value & 0x00FF0000 >> 16
```

is the same as

```
red = value & (0x00FF0000 >> 16)
```

Note that `(0x00FF0000 >> 16)` is just `0x000000FF`. The same happens for `green` and `blue`, so you get the same value three times. Hence it's grey.

The alpha value is different because `0xFF000000 >> 24` is `0xFFFFFFFF` due to the way the signed right shift works.

The solution is to rebracket. (I'd also use `>>>` for this, but it actually makes no difference because `alpha` gets shifted back 24 places left anyway).

```
alpha = (value & 0xFF000000) >>> 24;
red = (value & 0x00FF0000) >>> 16;
green = (value & 0x0000FF00) >>> 8;
blue = value & 0x000000FF;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This is the right answer. It works after correcting as such.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this code:

```
alpha = value & 0xFF000000 >> 24;         
       red = value & 0x00FF0000 >> 16;
   green = value & 0x0000FF00 >> 8;
   blue = value & 0x000000FF;
```

First masks with bitwise mask **and then shifts**, try the opposite. Shift then, bitmask with `0xFF`.

It probabbly has to do with byte formats and unsigned integers and [unsigned right shift in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811319/difference-between-and).

As already noted by [@Paul Boddington](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32594457/3591273) operator precedence plays a major part.

Comment: Thank you very much Nikos M. Your answer helped me to find the error. Actually the error was that I first shifted and then masked. When I changed the code as follows, the code worked as I expected. I got the hint from your answer :                                                                                          alpha = (value & 0xFF000000) >> 24;         
                   red = (value & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
                   green = (value & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
                   blue = value & 0x000000FF;

Comment: @SukhoLee, nice to hear, you can also accept if it helped you