# What's the meaning of ' >>>' operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I found a operator Ive never see before in this code

```
d[(a + 64 >>> 9 << 4) + 14] = a;
```

I know the << operator is left shift. But really confuse >>>.

Can you help me explain this?

Comment: [Zero-fill right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between operator >>> in Java and JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994783/what-is-the-difference-between-operator-in-java-and-javascript)

Comment: Zero fill right shift 
Shifts right by pushing zeros in from the left, and let the rightmost bits fall off

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the JavaScript >>> operator and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822350/what-is-the-javascript-operator-and-how-do-you-use-it)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zero fill right shift

Shifts right by pushing zeros in from the left, and let the rightmost bits fall off

```
Operation   Result     Same as      Result
5 >>> 1        2       0101 >>> 1    0010
```