# Why is AS3 right bit shift different than the same thing in Java?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash, bit-manipulation

Hard to explain without some code.. so

```
var junk:uint = uint(4294280300);

trace(junk.toString(2)); // returns 11111111111101011000010001101100
junk = junk >> 8;
trace(junk.toString(2)); // returns 11111111111111111111010110000100
```

and here is the Java part

```
long junk = 4294280300L;

System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(junk)); // returns 11111111111101011000010001101100
junk = junk >> 8;
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(junk)); // returns 111111111111010110000100
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve the same result in Java? I have tried using `>>>` instead of `>>` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know ActionScript at all, but it's for sure due to differences in the internal representation of numbers.

The type uint of ActionScript seem indeed to be an unsigned integer coded on 32 bits.
Additionally, the number appear to be converted into a signed integer before the right shift operation is performed. This counter-intuitive behavior explains the result.

You don't have this problem in Java because long is an integer number coded on 64 bits, and the value 4294280300  perfectly fits into 64 bits.
You would have observed the same result as in ActionScript if you have had used an int instead of a long.

Let's look at what JavaScript does to better understand what appears to happen in ActionScript:  JavaScript stores all numbers as double floating-point and you are sure to not lose precision on integers that can fit in 53 bits.
Trying with the same value, see that you get the same result as in ActionScript if you use `>>`, but  the same as Java if you use `>>>`.

ON JavaScript side, it appears that `>>` a.k.a arithmetic shift converts first the value to 32-bit signed integer, while it doesn's with `>>>` a.k.a logical shift.
That's weird, and wouldn't really surprising that ActionScript does something similar.

Interestingly, python has no `>>>`operator, always does an arithmetic shift, and seems to work even beyond 64 bits.

Given the popularity of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811319/difference-between-and)
or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994783/what-is-the-difference-between-operator-in-java-and-javascript), `>>` vs. `>>>` is a common source of confusion in languages where the two operators exist.

Comment: I see. Well, AS3 is a deprecated technology anyway. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmmm, but isn't 4294280300 smaller than the maximum value of an unsigned 32bit integer (4294967295)?

Comment: From the documentation for operator `>>` `Converts expression and shiftCount to 32-bit integers, and shifts all the bits in expression to the right by the number of places specified by the integer that results from the conversion of shiftCount. Bits that are shifted off the right end are discarded. To preserve the sign of the original expression, the bits on the left are filled in with 0 if the most significant bit (the bit farthest to the left) of expression is 0, and filled in with 1 if the most significant bit is 1.`  (cont'd)

Comment: ... So it appears that the shift operator ***converts its left operand to signed int*** before performing the shift. This is extremely counter-intuitive, but explains why the AS3 code works the way it does.  @QuentinC please feel free to incorporate this into your answer.  [AS3 operator `>>`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#bitwise_right_shift)

Comment: @Freshek Nope. JS does the same.Its all called the same root called EcmaScript