# Non cryptographic hashing in Java using unsigned integers

Tags: java, hash

I am looking for a hashing function that can be used for non cryptographic purposes in Java. The challenge is that most of the hashing functions return signed integer values (-,0,+) that cannot be used as identifier in every context (for example negative integers cannot be used in URLs). One solution to this problem is that I come up with is to use a 32 bit signed int and convert it to a 32 bit unsigned int and store it in a long. This works pretty well. However, 32 bit random information makes hash collisions too frequent in our setup. One way of solving this is to use a 64 bit hashing function (same SipHash works fine) and convert that signed integer to unsigned by shifting one to the right and having 0 in the MSB position. I was trying to achieve that with the Java >> operator but the results does not make sense.

```
//Using Guava
private final static HashFunction hashFunction = Hashing.sipHash24();

    private static int getRandomInt() {
        return hashFunction.newHasher().putLong(rnd.nextLong()).hash().asInt();
    }

    private static long getRandomLong(){
        return hashFunction.newHasher().putLong(rnd.nextLong()).hash().asLong();
    }
```

Bitshifting:

```
 System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(-2147483648L >> 1));
 1111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000
```

What am I missing and how could I have a 62 bit unsigned integer hash value stored in a 64 bit int (long) in Java?

UPDATE1:

After doing some research I finally found a way to correctly display the effect of >>> on a Long value:

```
        System.out.println(
          String.format("%64s", Long.toBinaryString(-2147483648L))
            .replace(' ', '0'));
        System.out.println(
          String.format("%64s", Long.toBinaryString(-2147483648L >>> 1))
            .replace(' ', '0'));

        1111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000
        0111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Why can't you use a negative value in a url? Also, try [`>>>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811319/difference-between-and) (unsigned right shift) instead of `>>` (signed right shift).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks! because /-123123/ looks awfully similar to /123123/ and there are routing based on this value that does not support it being negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a >> b`

shifts a to the right by b bits. On the left it repeats the bit that was already there (sign extending!).
Examples:

- 101010 >> 1 = 110101
- 010101 >> 1 = 001010

`a >>> b`

also shifts a to the right by b bits, but doesn't sign extend. It always adds in zeros on the left:

- 101010 >>> 1 = 010101
- 010101 >>> 1 = 001010