# Java >>> operator giving this output ? is it true?

Tags: java

I know what diffirences between >> and >>>. but I did not get the output that i expected.

example.

```
byte foo;

// this part printing -61 so no problem with this part
foo = -121; // -121 = 10000111
// foo >> 1 = 11000011 = -61
System.out.println( (byte) (foo >> 1) );  


foo = -121; // -121 = 10000111
// foo >>> 1 = 01000011 = 67
System.out.println( (byte) (foo >>> 1) );
// problem: why is this part printing -61 instead of 67 ?
```

thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811319/difference-between-and

Comment: Bitwise operators...from the documentation `The signed left shift operator "<<" shifts a bit pattern to the left, and the signed right shift operator ">>" shifts a bit pattern to the right. The bit pattern is given by the left-hand operand, and the number of positions to shift by the right-hand operand. The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position, while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on sign extension`...link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: Hackman and Progman obviously didn't bother to read the question!

Comment: This is not a dup... @davidxxx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`>>>` operates on `int` values, so it widens its arguments to `int` first.  So it gets sign-extended to

```
 11111111111111111111111110000111
```

which logical right shifts to

```
 01111111111111111111111111000011
```

which, when you take the last 8 bits as a cast to `byte` does, gives

```
 11000011
```

which is -61.

If you don't want that implicit sign extension before the shift, you'll have to write

```
(byte) ((foo & 0xFF) >>> 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was starting to investigate when I saw that `foo` gets treated like an `int` and then saw your answer. Totally makes sense!

Comment: do you know why java convert byte variables to int automaticilly ? this doesn't make sense ?

Answer (score 1):

Some background information in addition [Louis Wasserman's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45944461/2513200):

This is specified in [jls-15.19 Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):

> Unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) is performed on each operand separately. (Binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is not performed on the operands.)

And the [jls-5.6.1 Unary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1):

> - If the operand is of compile-time type Byte, Short, Character, or Integer, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8). The result is then promoted to a value of type int by a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) or an identity conversion (§5.1.1).
> - Otherwise, if the operand is of compile-time type Long, Float, or Double, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
> - **Otherwise, if the operand is of compile-time type byte, short, or char, it is promoted to a value of type int by a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2).**
> - Otherwise, a unary numeric operand remains as is and is not converted.

(emphasis mine)

And [5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

> A widening conversion of a signed integer value to an integral type T simply sign-extends the two's-complement representation of the integer value to fill the wider format.