# How does Java bit shift operator (>>>) work?

Tags: java, bit-shift

The output I calculated from right shifting the 2's complement of 20 and then converting the result to decimal does not match the output. Why does the code below generate such unexpected output?

```java
class OperatorExample{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  

        System.out.println(-20>>>2);  
    } 
}

output: 1073741819
```

Comment: Which output did you expect?

Comment: Did you know you were using an *unsigned* bit shift operator?

Comment: Maybe this helps: `(2^32 - 20) / 2^2 = 1073741819`

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811319/difference-between-and

Comment: Try this.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html

Comment: @Bubletan thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation is:

Take -20:

```
jshell> Integer.toBinaryString(-20)
$1 ==> "11111111111111111111111111101100"
```

Shift it right by 2, which removes the last two zeros:

```
jshell> Integer.toBinaryString(-20 >>> 2)
$2 ==> "111111111111111111111111111011"
```

And convert it to decimal:

```
jshell> 0b111111111111111111111111111011
$3 ==> 1073741819
```